# Is there a possibility to make shuffled array constant afterward?

Tags: php, shuffle

I have a card game with mixed cards (array with 100 cards, value 1-100, shuffled - alternative would be to random pick by id).

Each player gets a set of cards. The cards are played with POST/ submit.

My problem is that every time I post, the cards are mixed again. But the value of the cards should stay constant while assigned to card-variables.

Is there any possibility to make a random constant afterwards, so that the variable doesn´t get re-assigned when posting/loading?

```
function mixcarddeck()
{
    $carddeck = array(100);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $carddeck[$i] = $i + 1;
    }
    shuffle($carddeck);
}

function givecardvalue($i)
{
    $carddeck = mixcarddeck();
    return $carddeck[$i];
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It would help a lot if you added some code to show us how you shuffle and store the variables now.

Comment: Store the shuffled array into the session …? (Assuming you need this on a per-user basis only, and not share the same shuffled set of cards between multiple players or something like that.)

Comment: Hello,the aim is to use it for multiplayer.. As I´m really a beginner, I started with assigning five cards to one player.

Comment: here ist what I coded before: function mixcarddeck () {
$carddeck = array(100);
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    $carddeck[$i] = $i+1;}

shuffle($carddeck);



function givecardvalue($i) {
    $carddeck = mixcarddeck();
    return $carddeck[$i]; }

Comment: When do you call `givecardvalue`? Right now you generate a new deck everytime you call this function. It would be best to call this function once and store the result in a variable that you can then call from within the `givecardvalue` function.

Comment: Thank you very much!! My mistake was: I was calling: $a = givecardvalue(1); $b = givecardvalue(2), etc.. I´ll call it only once directly after definition, as you said, and return array with all cards as value :-)... Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

you can use $$ to make a dynamic variable in php instead of single $ if thats, what u want

```
 $variable="name";
    $$variable;

$$variabe is now (same as $name)
```

now generate random constant and make new variables each time so that new variable is assigned each time